# Upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04 offline

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, offline

I have been looking for a way so I can upgrade from `Ubuntu 17.10` to `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` **offline**.

There were tips in the internet but they were mostly done online.

thanks in advance

Comment: One easy method: 1) Backup your data. 2) Clean-install 18.04. 3) Restore your data.

Comment: 18.04 is an LTS version : DVD sets are available. https://www.osdisc.com/products

Answer (score 0):

First things first: backup, backup, backup!

Back up all of your important data to an external HDD. You could also `dd` the entire contents of your internal HDD to an external one if you want a complete 1:1 image of the HDD.

---

## Warning! I take no responsibility if this fails and you lose your data because you failed to back it up!

---

Before you begin, run this command to find out your username:

```
whoami
```

#### Write the output down! (Also write down your password)

---

Now for reinstalling:

1. Download the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS ISO
2. Burn the ISO to a DVD, or use the included Startup Disk Creator program to make a live USB drive.
3. Boot the install media you created in step #2
4. Choose to install Ubuntu
5. On the "installation type" screen, choose **Something Else**
6. Select Ubuntu system partition, and set its mount point as `/`. **Be sure to keep the same format type, the same size, and untick the "Format" checkbox** *(else all data on "/" will be deleted!)*
7. When you are asked to create your username and password, **USE THE ONES YOU WROTE DOWN EARLIER!!!** *(Else loose your data)*
8. After the installation finishes, follow the prompts to shutdown, and remove the installation media when it tells you to.
9. Reboot and cross your fingers.